# Change -xmx default value for apache marathon on debian

Tags: marathon

Hi I've installed Apache Marathon (latest version available on APT repo) on Debian 8.5 (Jessie). The configuration in 
    /etc/marathon/conf/
works very well for that kind of parameters but how can I change the default -xmx512m parameter?

regards
guenther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Marathon documentation](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/command-line-flags) Java options including `-Xmx`value is configured using `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable. You can set `JAVA_OPTS` for marathon by defining it in `/etc/default/marathon` like so `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -Xms384m"`